# How to trigger dropdown change event within code in Vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to trigger dropdown change event within Vue js method.

`<select id="idDropdown" v-model="Result.Value" v-on:change.prevent="changeSelection($event, 'somevalue')">`

Now how can I call the above changeSelection() method when dropdown button changes in the code in any vue js method. How to pass $event variable.

I have 2 dropdown buttons and when model value changes through code like this Result.Value = 10 then I want to trigger changeSelection method to bind some data in second dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to run the `changeSelection` yourself, it will be called automatically, when the selected option changes.

You don't need also the `.prevent` modifier.

**UPDATE**

If you set the selected option programmatically outside the select, then you will need a watcher, to call your function.

```
watch: {
   selected(newVal, oldVal) {
      this.changeSelection(null,newVal)
   }
}
```

```js
const { createApp } = Vue

const App = {
  data() {
    return { selected: null }
  },
  methods: {
    changeSelection(event, value) {
      if (event != null) console.log("event.target.value: " + event.target.value)
      console.log("value: " + value)
    }
  },
  watch: {
    selected(newVal, oldVal) {
      this.changeSelection(null,newVal)
    }
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 1.75; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app">
  Select: <select v-model="selected" v-on:change="changeSelection($event, 'somevalue')">
    <option value=1>1</option>
    <option value=2>2</option>
    <option value=3>3</option>
  </select><br/>
  Selected: {{selected}}<br/>
  <button @click="selected = 0">Set 0</button>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

Comment: Its not calling automatically changeSelection when I try to update dropdown model value in code like this Result.Value =10

Comment: Sure, since onChange event do occurs only if you select an option. You will need to `watch` the selected option instead.

Comment: That's working but in watch when calling  this.changeSelection(null,newVal) I want to pass $event not null as doing some operations in the method

Comment: As I said before, there is no event, when you change the value programmatically. You can only fake the event by passing an object instead of the event, like `{ target: { id: 'idDropdown, 'value: 1 } }`

Comment: Could you please accept my answer, if it has helped? Thank you!